# NFSv3 file lock problems when rp_filter is enabled (2)

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a server with bridged interfaces in multiple networks, for which I require rp_filter to be set to "2".
There's also an NFS server (supports v2 to v4.2).

Clients using NFSv4 are fine, clients using NFSv3 have issues with file lock. Every program that requires the use of a file lock, it just hang there.

I mention "rp_filter" because the only relevant result I found on Google, mentions that (although is for a specific backup/storage software), but the solution they give there is to disable rp"filter"... which I can't...

I wonder why NFSv4 works but not v3... does anyone know if there's any other solution?